# Why doesn't grid leave cells marked with "." empty?

Tags: html, css, css-grid

My attempt:

```css
#mygrid {
  border:1px solid black;
  width:160px;
  display:grid;
  grid-template-columns: 40px 40px 40px 40px;
  grid-template-areas: "a . . b";
}
```

```html
<div id = "mygrid">
  <div>hello</div>
  <div>there</div>
</div>
```

Shouldn't it place "there" into the last cell as the two middle ones are supposed to be left empty?

Comment: Since you haven't told it where you place the child elements inside the div, it's auto-filling them in order. All `.` means is that the cell doesn't have a specific name, not that it should be left blank.

Comment: Use `grid-area: a` on the first div and `grid-area: b` on the second div

Comment: well that sucks, naming them is precisely what I'm trying to avoid

Comment: or use `grid-column: -2` for the last item instead of `grid-template-areas`: see https://jsfiddle.net/c5wbvuhq/

Comment: Using a `.` to leave a grid are empty is just a convention, not a real feature. It doesn't tell the browser to leave that empty, it tells the developer that those items are intented to left emtpy but you need to make sure you leave them empty. Remember, it's just some convention, you could use `_` or any other character that you or your team decide that means "don't use this cell" but the browser has no idea what that means.

Comment: @arieljuod Its actually not just a convention, you can't use any other character to mark non-continuous cells empty, for example ". a ." works, "_ a _" does not.

Comment: @user81993 for your actual code on the question it does work using `_` as the area name https://codepen.io/anon/pen/vwGoPQ. You can't use `_` as the first area name but you can use a lot of characters, it doesn't have to be `.` https://codepen.io/anon/pen/OYNKrY. I can't find on MDN the valid area names, but `.` is not special, it's just one easy to remember from the valid names.

Comment: @arieljuod It works there because its a continuous area, it creates an area named "_", not an empty area. Its not about being first, "a . b ." works, "a _ b _" does not. "." is special, as mentioned in MDN https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout/Grid_Template_Areas#Leaving_a_grid_cell_empty

Comment: @user81993 thanks I found the specs https://drafts.csswg.org/css-grid/#grid-template-areas-null-cell-token and it's a "null cell token", I was confused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have defined 4 columns so the browser will fill them strating from the first one and will not *jump* the one in the middle defined by `.` unless you **explicitely** told it to do so.

If you want to simulate such behavior, you can simply define 2 columns and rely on gaps:

```css
#mygrid {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 160px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 40px 40px;
  grid-column-gap: 80px;
  grid-template-areas: "a  b";
}
```

```html
<div id="mygrid">
  <div>hello</div>
  <div>there</div>
</div>
```

Another idea is to rely on an empty element to fill those columns:

```css
#mygrid {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 160px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 40px 40px 40px 40px;
  grid-template-areas: "a i i b";
}

#mygrid:before {
  content:"";
  grid-area:i;
}
```

```html
<div id="mygrid">
  <div>hello</div>
  <div>there</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to place the `hello` to area `a` and `there` to area `b`. Do this

```css
#mygrid {
  border:1px solid black;
  width:160px;
  display:grid;
  grid-template-columns: 40px 40px 40px 40px;
  grid-template-areas: "a . . b";
}

/* Placing to grid areas */

#mygrid div:first-child {
  grid-area: a;
}

#mygrid div:last-child {
  grid-area: b;
}
```

```html
<div id = "mygrid">
  <div>hello</div>
  <div>there</div>
</div>
```